# Question related to algebraic varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $k$ be and algebraically closed field and $f,g\in k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ with $f$ an irreducible polynomial. Prove that if $V_{a}(f)$ $\subseteq$ $V_{a}(g)$, then $f|g$.

Where $V_{a}(f)=\{(a_{1},...,a_{n})\in k^{n}\text{ }|\text{ }f(a_{1},...,a_{n})=0\}$ and $V_{a}(g)=\{(a_{1},...,a_{n})\in k^{n}\text{ }|\text{ }g(a_{1},...,a_{n})=0\}$.

I would be grateful if you could help me about this issue.

Comment: Do you know the Nullstellensatz?

Answer (score 1):

Let $I := (f)$ be the ideal of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ generated by $f$. Since $V(f)\subset V(g)$, $g$ vanishes on $V(I)$.

The [Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz) tells us that there is some $r\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g^r \in I$. Hence, $f | g^r$. But since $f$ is irreducible, this implies that $f|g$.